# How to install CLI interpreter to run .php file in PhpStorm?

Tags: php, apache, phpstorm

I'm trying to open a `.php` file in Chrome for a while now but I couldn't because it seems like it doesn't have interpreter:

[image: PhpStorm PHP CLI setting]

Whenever I tried, it keeps on showing `Object not found`:

[image: Apache error]

When I use XAMPP, I have to type `localhost` just to make it appear but most of the time, it appears as `502 bad gateaway`. I really need help because I'm kinda bad at programming.

Comment: To open a PHP page you need a webserver with PHP installed on it. Xampp starts such a webserver and because of this you are able to open the page. So use xampp and post some log's of the apache in your xampp instance so that we can help you with the 502 error.

Comment: What you need is a PHP interpreter and optionally a webserver. When you are using Windows, you can just install PHP to use it for CLI. I am personally preferring running both in a local Ubuntu installation (just for free in the windows store). You can then use 127.0.0.1 to access both CLI and "web".

Comment: You should not change the question, only add updates to it. So now, you are asking something different. What you still need to do is to configure the apache vhost file to the proper path.

Comment: 1) As per your screenshot you have an Apache web server (be it standalone or part of XAMPP or another bundle). Configure it so it can execute .php files. 2) Once that done, you can configure a Deployment entry in PhpStorm -- there you define the URL that will be used when you use "Open in Browser" kind of commands in IDE. Actual deployment can be of "In place" type when no file copying is involved; Do not forget to mark such entry as Default for this project.

Comment: As for 502 error -- PhpStorm has built-in simple web server .. but it is very basic and can throw 502 errors even for a perfectly valid code (it works for some ppl and does not for others). Built-in web server URL is used when no default deployment entry is specified. URLs will be like `localhost:63342/PROJECT_NAME/file.php` -- this kind of URLs.

Comment: I have already configured everything, yet it gives me 502 bad getaway. Now, i'm gonna try configuring Docker.

Comment: CLI stands for Command-Line Interface. You don't want that.