# Can't connect the PHP CLI interpreter I downloaded with my IntelliJ IDE

Tags: php, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I wanted to start using PHP in IntelliJ so I had downloaded the PHP plugin in IntelliJ. I did some research and found out that I also need to download PHP CLI interpreter for localhost and configure it in IntelliJ's preferences.

I downloaded PHP version 7.4.5 and stored it in my computer. But when I enter IntelliJ's preferences to put it in as my project's PHP interpreter, I couldn't find it. Could you please help me with how to connect the PHP interpreter file I stored with my IntelliJ? Thank you so much!

**Image of the PHP file I downloaded:**
[image]

**Image of I try to configure my project's PHP CLI interpreter**
[image]

**When I click usr/bin/php, this appear**
[image]

**When I click Other Local, this appear**
[image]

**This shows the path to the file I downloaded**
[image]

**I also tried this, but it didn't work...**
[image]

Comment: `I downloaded PHP version 7.4.5 and stored it in my computer` Do you mean you INSTALLED PHP? Or you copied some file somewhere

Comment: I installed PHP 7.4.5 from PHP website: https://www.php.net/downloads.php

Comment: Maybe my problem got something to do with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58814468/how-to-install-cli-interpreter-to-run-php-file-in-phpstorm